# Group theory confusion for $|\langle g\rangle| = o(g)$

Tags: group-theory

From this intro to group theory text I'm reading:

The subgroup generated by $g$ is $\{g^n\ |\ n\in G \ and \  n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

So if we take $\mathbb{Z}_6$ = $(\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, +)$

And the group generated by the element $ \langle 2\rangle = (\{0, 2, 4\}, +)$

Then $|\langle 2\rangle | = 3$

But then the text gives the equation $|\langle g\rangle | = o(g)$

$|\langle2 \rangle| = o(g)$ = the smallest $n$ where $2n = e$ ($e$ is $0$ for $\mathbb{Z}$)

Here is where I get confused.

If $|\langle 2 \rangle|$ is $3$, then $o(2)$ must be $3$ as well, but $2^0 = e$.

So the smallest $n$ such that $2^n = e = 0$?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which text are your referring to?

Comment: http://math.mit.edu/~jwellens/Group%20Theory%20Forum.pdf
The equation $|<g>|$ = o(g) is given at the beginning of page 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\langle 2\rangle = \{2,4,0\}$ so $|\langle 2\rangle| = 3$.  Also $o(2) = 3$;  that is $3$ is the smallest positive integer such that $2\times 3 = 0$ in this group.  We do not consider $n=0$ when we look for the smallest $n$ so that $2 \times n = 0$.

Comment: Why is $2^3$ 0 and not 6?

Comment: In this group $\mathbb Z_6$, we have only elements $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, so of course no calculation in that group has answer $6$.  In that group, $2+2+2 = 0$.  You didn't say it here, but in order to write $(\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, +)$ I assume it has been explained before that $+$ is addition modulo $6$.

Comment: Ah! Now it makes sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

They ought to have specified: the order of an element $g$ of a group $G$ is the smallest *positive* number $n$ such that $g^n = e$. This is so that the statement is not vacuous; in a group *every* element $g$ satisfies $g^0 = e$.

Comment: (+1). The only I would stress here is that, being settled what does $g^n$ mean for $n \ge 1$ and  that $g^{-n}:=(g^{-1})^n$, then *by defining* $g^0:=e$ the property $g^ng^{-m}=g^{n-m}$ holds also for $m=n$ and then for every $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit confused because in the example you gave the group is in additive notation and in text they use multiplicative notation.

Try to think about the operation as $*$. The order of an element $g$ written $o(g)$ is the answer you get when you apply $*$ on $g$ repeatedly unitl you get $e$.

That is in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ $o(2)=3$ since this is an additive group we think about the operation as addition and get

$$
2+2+2=6\equiv_6 6.
$$

To give an example of a multiplicative group take $\mathbb(Z)_5^*$ which consists of the numbers $\{1,2,3,4 \}$ and we use multiplication as the operation and as $e$ we have $1$. Here $o(2)=4$ since

$$
2^4=2\cdot 2\cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2= 16\equiv_5 1
$$